# Nexus 7 ignores apple-touch-icon

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, bookmarks, nexus-7

1. Go to any website that has:

   ```
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
   ```

   For example: [bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/), [starbucks.com](http://www.starbucks.com/), or [play.com](http://www.play.com/).
2. Create a bookmark from the browsers.
3. Go to Bookmarks, and Add to Homescreen.

On other Android devices, the icon that appears on your homescreen will be the icon specified in one of the two tags above. On my Nexus 7 though, it always uses a bookmark icon with the site's favicon in the middle. I know the icons are working, because if you go into Chrome => Bookmarks, it shows the bookmarks with the apple-touch-icon there, just not on the homescreen.

Did this change in Jellybean? Is it a bug, or intentional for some reason? I can't find any mention of this behavior anywhere online.

Comment: I know this isn't gonna help but it would probably work if it's something like `<link rel="google-touch-icon" href="/google-touch-icon.png" />`. Nah, just kidding.

Comment: Not Nexus 7 specific. The changed the behaviour with "apple touch icons" in JellyBean. 
Doesn't work on my Galaxy Nexus either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Google is afraid of being sued by Apple for using "square icon with rounded corners". There is an issu on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125076. However there is information about fix version set to 25th release. I don't know if chromium and chrome versions have the same numbers, but last time I checked Chrome it was on v. 22. There is also a posted suggestion of introducing chrome specific Android-Icon.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that bug report is exactly what I was looking for! To clarify, it looks to be a bug/missing feature on Mobile Chrome. Of course, since Mobile Chrome replaced the Android Browser completely in Jellybean, that's why it appeared to be a Jellybean bug.

Weird though, that seems like a big feature to leave out. If it's because they don't want to get sued, then they could at least give us an android-touch-icon meta tag to replace it.